# Current shunt not working

Tags: shunt

I was using a 12 ohm current sensing resistor and I was getting 26mVAC across IN and IP.

When I switched to a 100mohm resistor then I was getting around 8.2mVAC across IN and IP

Load = 300W and current was approximately 1.3A and input voltage was 225 VAC for both shunts.

I am using an AM90E26 IC for voltage and current measuring.  The circuit below works for the 12ohm resistor.

[image: Current Sensing circuit]

Comment: What does "E" stand for?  Did you mean "ohms?"

Comment: yes, E stands for OHm

Comment: 50/60 Hz? How do you measure it in the right side end of the schematic?

Comment: There is a strong smell of danger about your circuit. Are you sure you know enough to assess the risks and how to operate a directly connected mains current monitoring circuit? You realise that IN, AGND and IP are all live and that therefore your attached devices are live? Why not use a current transformer or hall sensor which gives you isolation as well as eliminating problems with level shifting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 12 ohm resistor with 1.3A going through it should drop 15.6V so I'm not sure in what sense that is "working" if you only have 0.026V.

Sounds more like there is a short (not shown in your schematic) bypassing the shunt, with some parallel and series resistance.